# LLVM, Initialize an integer global variable with value 0

Tags: c++, llvm

I've been going in circles through the LLVM documentation / Stack Overflow and cannot figure out how an integer global variable should be initialized as 0 (first time using LLVM). This is some of my code currently:

```
TheModule = (argc > 1) ? new Module(argv[1], Context) : new Module("Filename", Context);

// Unrelated code

// currentGlobal->id is just a string
TheModule->getOrInsertGlobal(currentGlobal->id, Builder.getInt32Ty());
llvm::GlobalVariable* gVar = TheModule->getNamedGlobal(currentGlobal->id);
gVar->setLinkage(llvm::GlobalValue::CommonLinkage);
gVar->setAlignment(4);

// What replaces "???" below?
//gVar->setInitializer(???);
```

This almost does what I want, an example of output it can produce:

```
@a = common global i32, align 4
@b = common global i32, align 4
@c = common global i32, align 4
```

However, `clang foo.c -S -emit-llvm` produces this which I want as well:

```
@a = common global i32 0, align 4
@b = common global i32 0, align 4
@c = common global i32 0, align 4
```

As far as I can tell I need a `Constant*` where I have `"???"`, but am not sure how to do it: http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1GlobalVariable.html#a095f8f031d99ce3c0b25478713293dea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [one of the APInt constructors](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1APInt.html#a6286f2ba84c5ad11f4a90d57cb1dd293) to get a 0-valued `ConstantInt` (AP stands for Arbitrary Precision)

```
ConstantInt* const_int_val = ConstantInt::get(module->getContext(), APInt(32,0));
```

Then set your initializer value (a Constant subclass)

```
global_var->setInitializer(const_int_val);
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand getting the context for the `ConstantInt` argument, what an `APInt` is, and I am assuming `32` is just the bit representation of an integer. What about `StringRef("0")` and `10`?

Comment: The one I posted it's probably not the best constructor for what you need to do but I wanted it to be easy to use and resemble something like the atoi function. I edited the post to be simpler but the first version interpreted a string in a given radix: you were basically asking for the integer value of the string "10" in radix 10

Comment: Thank you, I have some footing finally, I went with `gVar->setInitializer(ConstantInt::get(Context, APInt(32, 0, true)));`, I believe it does the same thing

Comment: That's right, almost everything in llvm is a value-subclass and you usually have factory methods to get the right ones